# Password protecting web site using .htaccess files

Tags: cakephp-2.0

**How can I protect my website during development with *htaccess* in Cakephp? While I have only ftp username and password**

I used

.htaccess

AuthType Basic

AuthName "MyProjName"

AuthUserFile "/projectname/app/webroot/p.htpasswd"

require valid-user

Server error occure

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an CakePHP question, this is a Apache HTTP question.

If you need to control HTTP Auth with users data stored in MySQL database that is managed by some cakephp app, you may need to search for "htaccess mysql user", and check the properly hashing passwords to support that feature.